# jquery-validate - php embedded html forms

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

Can someone give me a hand with this please? I have been using jquery-validate without issues for html forms until I came across an issue with HTML forms embedded in php.

The example below is using jquery and jquery-validate. 
Form1 is validating the email field fine. Form3 however is not validating the number field (form3 is embedded in php).

I have attempted to comment out all form1 validation to ensure it wasn't multiple forms causing the issue.

I also tried commenting out the submitHandler from the javascript for form3 and this prevented form3 from submitting so this tells me that something is working it's just not validating the number field in form3.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate( {
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent("span").next("div") );
        },

        debug:true,
        wrapper: "li", 
        submitHandler: function(){
            form.submit();
        },
        rules: {                
            email: {required:false, email:true},
        },

        messages: {
            email: "Enter a valid email address",
        }
    })

    $("#form3").validate( {
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent("span").next("div") );
        },

        debug:true,
        wrapper: "li", 
        submitHandler: function(){
            form3.submit();
        },

        rules: {                
            quotaLimit: {required:true, number:true},
        },

        messages: {
            quotaLimit: "Enter a valid quota limit",
        }
    })
});
</script>

<br>

<div class="tab-button-row" style="position:relative;">
<a href="#" class="tab-button" onclick="toggleTab('editUserContent', 'details');">User Details</a>
<a href="#" class="tab-button" onclick="toggleTab('editUserContent','quotas');">Quota and Limits</a>
</div>
<br>

<div id="editUserContent">
<div id="details">
    <form id=form1 method=POST
          action="index.php?function=edituser&command=save&username=<?php echo $user->{"username"}; ?>"
          name=form>

        <?php
        if ($user->{'authenticationType'} == 0) {
            $visible = "";
        } else {
            $visible = "style='display:none;'";
        }
        ?>

        <table class="list">
            <tr>
                <td colspan=5><b>Edit Details</td>
                </td>
                <td width=25%><input type=submit value=save></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="fname" value="<?php echo $user->{"fname"};?>">
                </td>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="lname" value="<?php echo $user->{"lname"};?>">
                </td>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td>
                    <span>
                    <input name="email" value="<?php echo $user->{"email"};?>" class='validate'>
                    </span>
                <div></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <table class="list" <?php echo $visible; ?>>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=5><b>Password Settings</td>
                </td>
                <td width=25%><input type=submit value=save></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Set Password</td>
                <td><input type=checkbox name=change_password></td>
                <td>New Password:</td>
                <td><input name="password" type=password></td>
                <td>Re-enter Password:</td>
                <td><input name="re_password" type=password></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="quotas">
    <?php
    $table = new Table();
    $name = new Column("Quota Period");
    $name->render = function($data, $id)
    {
        echo $data->{'period'};
    };

    $desc = new Column("Quota Limit(MB)");
    $desc->render = function($data, $id)
    {
        echo $data->{'quotaLimit'};
    };

    $owner = new Column("Group Owner");
    $owner->render = function($data, $id)
    {
        if (isset($data->{'owner'})) {
            echo "<a href=index.php?function=editgroup&group=" . $data->{'ownerid'} . ">" . $data->{'owner'} . "</a>";
        }
    };

    $reached = new Column("Quota Reached");
    $reached->render = function($data, $id)
    {
        if ($data->{'exceeded'} == true) {
            echo "true";
        } else {
            echo "false";
        }
    };

    $ops = new Column("Operations");
    $ops->render = function($data, $id)
    {
        if (!isset($quotas[$i]->{'owner'})) {
            echo "<a href=index.php?function=edituser&command=deletequota&username=" . $_GET['username'] . "&period=";
            echo $data->{'period'} . "&quotaLimit=" . $data->{'quotaLimit'} . ">delete</a>";
        }
    };

    $table->addColumn($name);
    $table->addColumn($desc);
    $table->addColumn($owner);
    $table->addColumn($reached);
    $table->addColumn($ops);
    $table->setData($quotas);
    $table->footerMethod = function($footerArgs)
    {
        echo" <form id=form3 method=POST action=index.php?function=edituser&command=addquota&username=" . $_GET['username'] . ">";
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<select name='period'>";
        echo "<option>NONE</option>";
        echo "<option>DAY</option>";
        echo "<option>WEEK</option>";
        echo "<option>MONTH</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo "<span><input name=quotaLimit class='validate' /></span><div></div>";
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=submit value='Add/Set'></td></tr>";
        echo "</form>";
    };

    $table->render();
    ?>

</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
initToggleTab("editUserContent", "details");
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the source of the final HTML to see if the form looks as you expect? Try creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the static HTML and the JavaScript. You need to determine what part of that combo isn't working and then you can ensure that the PHP outputs what you need.

Comment: the only issue I can see is with Chrome only. The </form> end tag is directly after the <form> start. However this doesn't happen on Firefox and Firefox isn't validating form3 either. 
Form3 appears pretty well as it looks above

Comment: Please post the HTML _as rendered in the browser_ so we can at least have a shot at reproducing something.

Comment: Just as a reminder you can not nest `<tr>` tags inside `<form>` tag. also consider putting html elements attribute values between quotation marks as recommended by W3C. I really tried to reproduce you problem but in all of the cases the form gets validated. You should consider setting up a jsFiddle if you want to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. Managed to fix the issue by moving the form tags outside of the table to where it is rendered by php:

```
    $table->footerMethod = function($footerArgs)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<select name='period'>";
        echo "<option>NONE</option>";
        echo "<option>DAY</option>";
        echo "<option>WEEK</option>";
        echo "<option>MONTH</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo "<span><input name=\"quotaLimit\" class=\"validate\" type='text' /></span><div></div>";
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=submit value='Add/Set'></td></tr>";
    };

    echo" <form id=form3 method=POST action=index.php?function=edituser&command=addquota&username=" . $_GET['username'] . ">";
    $table->render();
    echo "</form>";
```